# Raspberry camera error: "mmal: No data received from sensor"

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi

I used successfully my raspberry camera times ago.
Now I tried again to acquire a image with the `raspistill -o image.jpg` command; the red led on the camera flashes, but I get this error:

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. 
Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

Of course the camera connections are fine. Is there any other way to check if the camera is still working?

Comment: I got the same error even for the newly purchased camera module. Finally solved by doing a firmware upgrade. [How do you update your Raspberry Pi to get the latest firmware?](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/11/29/raspberry-pi-4-firmware-update-pi-4-now-runs-cooler-than-ever/)

Answer (score 14):

This error usually appears because of a faulty connection with the camera.
I had the exact same problem in different camera+Pi configurations. The following case is what I encountered:

1. The connector is not correctly inserted either in the camera or in the Pi.
2. The Sunny connector (the small yellow one on the camera) is not connected well.
   (now it gets interesting)
3. If you often remove and reinsert the camera in the Pi please be sure to remove all power from the Pi. The sensor is very sensitive and a spark on the wrong pin could burn it. (I did this already unfortunately)
   This could also trigger a problem with the Pi connector pins. It was somewhat confirmed that for Pi2 the connector may have some bad soldering which could lead to cold contact soldering. You can fix this by using some flux on the pins and then pass the soldering iron hot end over the pins to remake the connection.
4. I used a longer cable that had both connectors on the same side of the cable. If you connect it like it is you can burn your sensor and the Pi will not start because of the power surge (also the camera gets very hot in this case). DO NOT REMOVE IT from the Pi without removing power before. To a cable like this you have to remove the blue plastic from one end and bend the connector with the contacts on the other side. Insert this end in the camera since this will not be removed/inserted as often as the Pi end.

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1` still i had same error. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the silver contacts are well inserted into the PCB connector. 
[(video here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GImeVqHQzsE)

Also, make sure that the sunny connector is firmly attached. 
[image: Sunny connector]

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same problem too, until I found a solution.

I **removed** the **sunny connector**(the yellow thingy below the camera in the board) and fixed it in the **same** place. The camera is working fine after trying this.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue. I have find out it was a **power supply** issue. 
Try to change your cable and/or your raspberry power supply adaptor.

You check if this is your reason of your problem by typing:
`$ dmesg`

if you see something like this:
`[   44.152029] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)`

-> Then replace your power supply! :D

Answer (score 0):

The only fix for me was to purchase a new camera.

- No real root causes identified.
- My problem was I put the camera in, while the Pi was on. which might
  have made the camera shot. i.e the camera module is static sensitive
  and it's possible that it's been damaged

Unfortunately if this is the case there's nothing you can realistically do to fix it, just get a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This specific error shows when another application is using the camera. In my case, it was motion.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the cable is placed the wrong way. I had this problem and after multiple tries I realized that was the problem.